# Videos in featured area keep playing, even after another video has been selected

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

The website www.newswars.org has a problem with the featured videos at the top of the home page.

When you click a video it plays in the featured area. If I click another video in the featured video, the old video continues to play.

I need to make it that the old video stops playing when the new video starts playing in the featured section.

Don't mind if the previous video loses its place at all...

Comment: Are you ok with losing the place you were in the video when another is clicked?

Comment: Hi DickieBoy. Absolutely fine with that...

Comment: When another video is clicked remove the container with the video in it and store the html. If the same video gets clicked again put it back in. This will stop the video playing and reset the time played. The other option is to hook into the youtube api by appending some query strings to the url and send a pause to the box. As far as i know this dosent work in ie7

Comment: The first option sounds fine, given that IE7 must work for this fix. I'm such a noob I have no idea to implement what you have said. Are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Have a look at these functions